# Proper use of submodules in .NET solutions

Tags: git-submodules

I have a library I wrote with a structure like this:

```
SolutionA\
--Source\
  --Core\
  --Tests\
--Tools\
  --TestFramework\
  --MockTool\
SolutionA.sln
```

I want to include this as a submodule for `SolutionB`.  If I use this entire structure as a submodule, it would get a bunch of stuff that `SolutionB` doesn't care about; it doesn't care about `SolutionA.sln`; it doesn't care about `Tests\`; it doesn't care about `Tools\`.  Really, `SolutionB` only cares about `Core\`.

It looks like I need a separate repository for `Core\`.  So is it usual practice to have two repositories for .NET solutions whose source is used by other solutions?  One for only the (non-test) code itself (plus needed libraries), and one for the test tools and solution file?

Comment: Are you really sharing the source between solutions?  Or do you really need to compile "Solution A", then share it's class library DLL with other solutions?

Comment: That's actually what I have been doing, but as more and more solutions refer to SolutionA, it becomes a real hassle to copy over a new dll to each one when I make an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions are simply containers for one or more projects; which may fall under the same "solution" folder or somewhere externally.

If you have a project, in this case "Core" then you can reference that project source directly from one or more solutions.  In this case, SolutionA and SolutionB.

The extraneous stuff like Tests\, TestFramework\, MockTool\, etc, unless required by Core, don't have to be included in your other solution.

Make sense?

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I need my build server to be able to pull what it needs to build SolutionB all by itself.  I could manually set up the .sln structure on the build server, and have it pull in repositories into that folder, but I'd rather have a clone-n-go strategy here.  (Build server --> git clone uri/to/SolutionB.git --> go).

Comment: (With perhaps a submodule init + update, which TeamCity's git plugin can be configured to do)

Comment: On second thought, going forward I'll probably end up using this solution (with a couple modifications).  There's simply too many shared resources among the repositories to copy into each one, and I'm writing so many bespoke applications there's going to be many more repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You COULD solve this with git-submodules (your tag leads me top believe that you use git). I don't know what the "usual practice" for stuff like this is.

As reply to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537371/how-to-deal-with-git-submodules-in-visual-studio-solutions-with-different-layout) about how to deal with submodules, [dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180471/dirk) proposed to use nuget (the package manager for the .NET Framework. see http://nuget.org) to solve a related problem. Seems to be a good fit for you, as you would get controlled updates for the dll, dependency management if you need it and (at least at the client side) good tool support.

Scott Hanselmann has a good [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetForTheEnterpriseNuGetInAContinuousIntegrationAutomatedBuildSystem.aspx) how to integrate nuget into Continous Integration.